# Writing Java from a Text Editor

Tags: java, tomcat, web, text-editor

As a project, I wanted to build a personal website using Java for the server-side code.  I am very new to Java and wanted to know if it was possible to write Java using a simple text editor, upload the file into a file directory in Apache Tomcat where the corresponding JS and HTML file sits (for practice purposes only), and then run the web project through the HTML file.

I do this with php through LAMP all of the time, and was hoping Java might work that way as well.

Comment: What you should upload to Apache Tomcat is a compiled Java code which has .class extension. I would suggest you to read JavaEE documentation on creating Web Applications. Usually they are packaged into an archive file with .war extension. Also its better to use an IDE for faster development.

Comment: Thanks Kiran, I will review the documentation.  However, will I not be able to just upload a .java file that is uncompiled into the directory?  I know this sounds sophomoric, but I can only relate to php, which only requires me to write code, add a .php extension, and that's it.

Comment: Yes, you cannot run java code unless it is compiled. AFAIK, Apache Tomcat does not do the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its very much possible. Even though you may find it bit difficult without the help of IDE, this should not make any difference. Convert the files to proper class files and upload it, that should do

Comment: Thanks LPD, I downloaded NetBeans, but I am just so used to doing things from scratch.  I understand that Java is much more extensive, so eventually I will use an IDE.  Right now, I just want to experiment with loops, DB connection strings, and, of course, output to HTML.

Comment: Yes. All the best. I wpuld suggest if u are starting afresh start with eclipse, as I myself found eclipse much faster than netbeans[person experience only]. Accept if you found it useful and close off this question

Answer (score 0):

Though i agree with above answer.But you can also go for hot deployment plugins for example mvn:jetty plugin for hot deployment of your website, but for that it needs to be maven project.Also grails and many other framework has this features inbuilt.

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh, I have never heard of hot deployment plugins.  I will look into that.  For now, I wanted to be as basic as possible, so I could get a thorough sense of what is going on in the Java environment.